# Multiple OR condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a where clause like that:

```
WHERE
T1.update_date >= @d 
  OR T2.update_date >= @d
  OR T3.update_date >= @d 
  OR T4.update_date >= @d 
  OR T5.update_date >= @d 
  OR T6.update_date >= @d 
  OR T7.update_date >= @d 
  OR T8.update_date >= @d 
  OR T9.update_date >= @d 
  OR T10.update_date >= @d 
  OR T11.update_date >= @d
```

How can I optimize that ?

Comment: Why do you need to optimize it? The SQL Server has optimizer that can do this for you.

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be optimized?

Comment: Any indexes on those columns? Also, what does your execution plan say?

Comment: In my case it takes 4 minutes with two conditions and 20 minutes with 5, that is very slow.

Comment: I don't have right on the database, no permission to view the execution also :(

Comment: What about the rest of the query? Can you show it? Also, is this a self join?

Comment: Make sure there's an index on update_date in each table. You may also get some mileage from splitting the query up into unions with a single table in each where clause, but that may become a pain to maintain.

Comment: seem that you have 11 Table  in join .. show the sql code  please ..

Comment: In fact, it is a complex large Query I optimized the code, left just these conditions to figure out the deltas. thx for all

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to see the complete query to give you a complete answer.

However, assuming you are doing a self-join to table T 11 times, you can simplify your query and possibly improve the performance by applying the filter in a CTE first.

```
WITH T
AS (
SELECT *
FROM basetable
WHERE Update_date >= @d
)
SELECT *
FROM T AS t1
INNER JOIN T AS t2
    ON t1.Pk = t2.Pk
INNER JOIN T AS t3
    ON t1.Pk = t3.Pk;
```

If you filter in the CTE, all subsequent references to the CTE will already include the filter.  Depending on the rest of your query, this could improve performance by limiting the filter to a single pass.  It also compacts the code and makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: Sorry I can't share all the query, also i guess it's useless. By the way,
It's not a self join